# Count checked checkboxes in React.js

Tags: javascript, checkbox, reactjs

I'm using a document structure like this

```
render() {
return (
    <div className="MyComponent">
        <ul className="">
            {parseRecommendations(this.props.recommendations)}
        </ul>
    </div>
);
}

function parseRecomendations(recommendations) {
    return recommendations.map((recommendation, key) => {
        return (<Recommendation data={recommendation} key={key} />);
    });
}
```

Where each Recommendation is its own component containing a checkbox

```
class Recommendation extends Component {
    const recommendation = this.props.data;
    const pageUrl = recommendation.url;

    return (
        <li className="article-item" key={key}>
            <div className="article-info">
                <input type="checkbox" defaultChecked="checked" aria-described-by={recommendation.pii} />
                <a className="journal-title" href={pageUrl} id={recommendation.pii}>{recommendation.title}</a>
            </div>
        </li>
    );
```

I'd like to have a title saying [Download (x) PDFs], where x is the number of selected checkboxes. How do I find the value of x in this case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to store information about whether input is "checked" in your data. Then, simply count items with truthy "checked" flag.

Here is my solution. You should be able to get principle here and modify your code.

```
const data = [
    { checked: false, value: 'document 1' },
    { checked: true, value: 'document 2' },
    { checked: true, value: 'document 3' },
    { checked: false, value: 'document 4' },
    { checked: false, value: 'document 5' },
];

const Item = props => (
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" checked={props.checked} onChange={props.onCheckChange} />
        { props.value }
    </div>
)
var Hello = React.createClass({
    getInitialState() {
        return {
            items: this.props.items.concat(),
        };
    },

    onCheckChange(idx) {
        return () => {
            const items = this.state.items.concat();
            items[idx].checked = !items[idx].checked;
            this.setState({items});
        }
    },

    totalChecked() {
        return this.state.items.filter(props => props.checked).length;
    },

  render() {
    return (
            <div>
                { this.state.items.map((props, idx) => (
                    <Item {...props} key={idx} onCheckChange={this.onCheckChange(idx)} />
                )) }
                Total checked: { this.totalChecked() }
            </div>
        );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello items={data} />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Comment: Instead of counting them up a tally count be maintained within onCheckChange and stored in state. Might not be ideal, but is a viable alternative.

Comment: The less state you maintain, the better. Counting total is not expensive. Personally, would not store it in state. On the other hand, I agree with you. In certain cases it's wise to cache results of some operations.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to get the number of selected check-boxes you can try this

```
let checkedBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[name=chkBox]:checked');
```

Then get the total checked boxes via `checkedBoxes.length`

**Edit:**

Instead of querying whole `document`. You can get the nearest possible parent via `getElementsByClassName` or `getElementById` and then apply `querySelectorAll` on that element.

e.g

`let elem = document.getElementsByClassName("MyComponent");`

```
let checkedBoxes = elem.querySelectorAll('input[name=chkBox]:checked');
```

Comment: Providing such answer, please, at least advise OP to apply scope - not to query `document`.

Answer (score 0):

You also could obtain the total of selected checkboxes by element type. The "console.log(totalSelectedCheckboxes)" will print them when the state of totalSelectedCheckboxes change using useEffect Hook.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const RenderCheckboxes = () => {
    const [totalSelectedCheckboxes, setTotalSelectedCheckboxes] = useState(0);
    function handleChk() {
        setTotalSelectedCheckboxes(document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length);
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(totalSelectedCheckboxes);
    }, [totalSelectedCheckboxes]);
    return (<div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" value={1} onChange={() => handleChk()} />Chk1
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" value={2} onChange={() => handleChk()} />Chk2
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" value={2} onChange={() => handleChk()} />Chk2
        </div>
    </div>);
}
export default RenderCheckboxes;
```